# City ,Town ,Village latitude ,longitude of india as json

Tags: json, api, resources, latitude-longitude

Any one suggest any source to get Indian city, village town LAT long as JSON [link](https://www.back4app.com/database/back4app/india-cities-database/get-started/javascript/rest-api/fetch?objectClassSlug=api-list-all-cities-india#get-your-code), I have found some resource where some town  are missing